# JQuery: How to check if element has only this class, and no other class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, select

I'm trying to come up with a way to select Element 2.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="qe datepicker">Element 1</div>
    <div class="qe">Element 2</div>
    <div class="qe fileuploader">Element 3</div>
    <div class="qe fileuploader datepicker">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

Though I haven't tested this code, I can do something like this, but it's kinda stupid and I want a more generic way:

```
var wanted_elements = $('.wrapper').children('.qe').not('.datepicker').not('.fileuploader');
```

Any thoughts on this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to select the second child or the element that has only the `qe` class?

Comment: I want to select all elements that ONLY have qe, and no other class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".wrapper").children("[class=qe]")
```

Change the selector to match elements where the `class` equals `"qe"`.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Same here. `filter` is the generic solution that works for everything so we're probably used to resort to that. `=]`

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the attribute selector:

```
$('.wrapper>[class=qe]')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdNaf/